# How to implement an activity for loading a file from web

Tags: android, android-activity, loading, back-button

My Android app starts on an activity named `LoadingActivity`. This activity loads a few files of my webserver. First it checks a timestamp in a text file on my server and checks if this timestamp is newer than one stored on the device. If it is, it loads the content of another file on my webserver and saves this to a file on the device.
When all this is done, I would like to go to another activity, `MainActivity`.
I do all this in the `onWindowFocusChanged` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    URL urlUpdated = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        urlUpdated = new URL("http://someurl.com/timestamp.txt");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlUpdated.openStream()));

        String updated = "";
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            updated = updated + inputLine;
        in.close();

        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        String lastUpdated = preferences.getString("lastUpdated", "");

        if (!lastUpdated.equals(updated)) {
            // Download JSON file (schedule)
            String schedule = "";
            URL urlSchedule;
            urlSchedule = new URL("http://someurl.com/downloadMe.txt");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlSchedule.openStream()));
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                schedule = schedule + inputLine;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, schedule);

            // Write schedule to file
            String PATH = "/data/data/com.codeinacup.NibeFestival/";    
            File file = new File(PATH + "Schedule.json");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
            writer.write(schedule);
            writer.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            // Update last updated preference
            editor.putString("lastUpdated", updated);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Go to next MainActivity
    Intent scheduleIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(scheduleIntent);
}
```

My problem is that when doing this, my `LoadingActivity` will be displayed but disappear again *very fast* and the screen will turn black for a couple of seconds and then `MainActivity` appears. Then, when the user press the back button, it will go back to `MainActivity` again. I found it obvious, that the back button should go back to `LoadingActivity`.

So my question is, how would I implement an activity for loading correctly? My idea of a loading activity is:

- Displayed when the application launches
- Downloads the files
- Goes to the next activity, `MainActivity`
- When at `MainActivity` and pressing the back button, the application should quit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onWindowFocusChanged gets called when the Activity gains or loses focus. So you start your Activity and it calls onWindowFocusChanged, because it gains focus. When it's finished loading your stuff it starts the MainActivity and loses focus again but executes the method again.

What I would do is create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which loads your stuff and executes the task in the MainActivity. And it would be nice if you show the user something, so that he knows the app is loading something. [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

No need of 2 Activitys.

Hope it helps.
Regards
Dominic

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see. Using `noWindowFocusChanged` isn't ideal then. I'll take a look at AsyncTasks. Actually, I have two activities because I'ld like to display an image and a progress bar while loading the files.

Comment: You can display the progress bar in a dialog over the MainActivity. Thats the sense of a ProgressDialog

Comment: Thank you for your help. I definitely did this all wrong. I have not made an AsyncTask instead and I call it from my MainActivity. Then I have created a listener to do a callback to update the MainActivity when the files has been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think the smartest thing to do is not seperate the download in a second activity.

Usually, I like doing my web access in the same activity but with threading. I use an asynctask to do my web access.

Create an asynchtask, and have it run at the launch of your mainactivity. It will display when app launches, download the files, go to MainActivity, and follow your request for the return button.

This SDK doc on Asynctask is very good: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html it helped me .

And the tutorial that really cleared it up for me was the following by Lars Vogel: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Hope I helped.

Comment: Tahnk you for your help. Using AsyncTask and doing it in the MainActivity is definitely the way to do it. This is way easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can do all this function of loading files in a thread or use async task 
and you shoud call

```
          this.finsish();
```